# Could not find or load main class jdk1.7

Tags: myeclipse

Issue: 
Getting below error when executing simple 'Hello World' Java Application from Myeclipse 2013 SR2. 
Same Errors comes when running internal Tomcat server.

Error: Could not find or load main class jdk1.7.0_40

Environment: Windows 7, 64 bit machine 
JDK 7 installed as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40

Also machine has C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40 -- Just for your information

Enviroment set as:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40 
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;.; 
PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;
```

Also In Myeclipse:Installed JRE is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40 JDK path.

One Strange observation is that: 
1. While installing Myeclipse 2013 SR2 on XP it is getting installed in C:\Program Files\ 
However for this machine it was installed on "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\MyEclipse Professional\myeclipse.exe" 
Even installed using administrator rights. When try to change installation directory path during isntallation to program 
files, showing tool tip as restricted access.So We installed Myeclipse 2013 on 
"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\MyEclipse Professional\myeclipse.exe"

Is this problem? or There is another issue.

Please guide the fix this issue.

Regards, 
Dattaprasad

Comment: Installing into AppData is not a problem. See http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-27545.html for more information. Regarding your problem, is that the exact error message? What type of project is it (you can't run a Java project on Tomcat)? How are you trying to run the program? Can you add the source code for your HelloWorld program?

Comment: Please go through http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=135070   for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else sees this, from discussion on the MyEclipse forum, it seems that the problem lay with the use of update 40 of the Java 7 JDK. The user switched to update 25 and had no problems. I tried it with update 45 and had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Install 64 bit Machine supported JDK [jdk-7u51-windows-x64.exe](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-windows-x64.exe) for run java programs. Don't use 32 bit JDK  [jdk-7u51-windows-i586.exe](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-windows-i586.exe) on 64 bit Machines.